# I would like to create a customize grid view on a sharepoint page in SP2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, development, gridview, cewp

I would like to create a customize grid view in SharePoint using a list that has already been created. the tools I have to do so are SharePoint designer and a CEWP.

I have some coding experience but what like t know how to start this process for creating a customize grid view with colors and spacing.

please HELP!!!

Comment: Perhaps you could use a combination of jquery and client object model

Answer (score 0):

Start with jquery data tables along with CSOM/REST API calls. The below link should get you started. All the best with your work.
[Rest and datatables](http://summit7systems.com/who-needs-a-data-view-web-part-sharepoint-rest-and-datatables-net/)